# Identity EmailService not firing when attempting to send confirmation email

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-identity

I've been modifying my implementation of ASP.Net Identity in my WebForms application. My modifications have caused my EmailService's SendAsync function to not fire and i'm not sure why. The only thing i can think of is how i am instantiating the UserManager on the register page. Before i was doing *var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();* and now i'm doing *var manager = new DecisionLogicIdentity.ApplicationUserManager(userStore);*. I am setting the EmailService in the Create function of the UserManager (manager.EmailService = new EmailService();). The SendGrid implementation was working prior to my change to how i call the UserManager. Does anyone have any idea what i am missing here?

**Register.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<DecisionLogicIdentity.ApplicationDbContext>();
    var userStore = new DecisionLogicIdentity.UserStore<DecisionLogicIdentity.ApplicationUser>(context)
    {
        CompanyId = Int32.Parse(CompanyId.Text)
    };
    var manager = new DecisionLogicIdentity.ApplicationUserManager(userStore);
    var signinManager = new DecisionLogicIdentity.ApplicationSignInManager(manager, HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);

    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("SampleAppName");
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(provider.Create("SampleTokenName"));

    var user = new DecisionLogicIdentity.ApplicationUser()
    {
        CompanyId = Int32.Parse(CompanyId.Text),
        UserName = Email.Text,
        Email = Email.Text,
        IsExpired = false,
        IsDeleted = false
    };

    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        user = userStore.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
        string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);

        manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

        //signinManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        //signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, true, shouldLockout: true);

        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**EmailService:**

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }

    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGrid--APIKey"].ToString());
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress("someemail@somedomain.com"),
            new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress(message.Destination),
            message.Subject,
            message.Body,
            message.Body);

        msg.Attachments = null;

        await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserManager:**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)//, IIdentityMessageService emailService)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
                                new DecisionLogicIdentity.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
                                context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>() as DatabaseContext));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserLockoutMinutes"].ToString()));
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserMaxLoginAttempts"].ToString());

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("SampleAppName");
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(provider.Create("SampleTokenName"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs the answer to this, I was able to get this functioning by modifying my UserManager like so:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store, IIdentityMessageService emailService)
        : base(store)
    {
        this.EmailService = emailService;
    }
...
```

And when instantiating the UserManager:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore, new EmailService());
```